# Why do I see a flag?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, flag-queue

Someone (or thing) flagged a post. I took action on it, so there's nothing I can do about it.

However, it still shows that there is an open flag on the menu.

[image]

Why? If there's nothing I can do, why show that 1?

Comment: Ugh, it's on a post that you flagged, and that number is a global cache.  Not a fun fix, but I'll get to it.

Comment: To further clarify, we don't show you posts in the /tools/flagged queue if you've already flagged them.

Comment: @JarrodDixon that number stops shows only after moderator takes action on that particular flagged post.

Comment: @JarrodDixon *Please* fix it!! It's just sitting there for quite some time now

Comment: @JarrodDixon I suspect this bug is related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1173/759